# UIScrollView Stop working after push view to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

The scrollview in my main page stop working if I push something to the navigation controller and then pop back to the main page. It works normally if I reopen the application without pushing anything to the navigation controller yet. The scrollview is a horizontal scrollview which extends beyond the frame. I use it to scroll through buttons like when you switch application in iOS (iOS multitasking).

This is the code where I push a new vc

```
    UIViewController *newVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];    
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"promo %i detail view",[sender tag]];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [newVC.view addSubview:label];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

when that view controller is popped and navigation controller move back to the main page I hide the navigationBar.

```
    - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
        if(viewController == self){
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            NSLog(@"%d", [self.scrollMenuBar isScrollEnabled]);
        }
    }
```

checking isScrollEnable return true.

I tried pushing a normal modal view and the same problem occur.

Comment: also check the contentsize of the scrollView, does it remain the same.? after poping

Comment: yes, it remains the same @Bonnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by creating the UIScrollview and the button inside it programmatically. Not sure what I did wrong with storyboard, but it's a pain.

Comment: Maybe disabling Autolayout would have solve the problem also.

Answer (score 1):

If you resize the scroll view content size in the viewDidLayoutSubview function it will work again.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self resizeScrollViewContent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add
`[self.scrollbarMenu setScrollEnabled:YES];` in viewdidAppear of main page

Add

```
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width , height)];
```

Still if it doesnt work 
2 possibilities

1. Memory is not valid.
2. Some other view comes above the scrollview

Comment: Add content size also there and try again

Comment: still doesn't work, and I checked that scrollEnable and contentSize remains the same after pop

Comment: The buttons in scrollview is still clickable though.