# UIScrollView scroll not working after pushed with a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, contentsize

I'm having an odd problem. I have a UIScrollView in a part of view hierarchy. It's working just fine when the view is presented via UITabBarController, but doesn't work at all after it is pushed with a Navigation controller (it is the third vc pushed atop the root). The scroll view was created in storyboard and the following lines are in the viewDidAppear method:

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 468.0f);
```

Any ideas, or suggestions? If you need shots of scrollview attributes inspector let me know. Here's the call method. The error might be somewhere inside here.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                                 bundle:nil];
    MKontaktViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Kontakt"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                         animated:YES];
```

Thanks,
Churchill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you resize the scroll view content size in the viewDidLayoutSubview function it will work again.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self resizeScrollViewContent];
}
```

and
[here same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539058/uiscrollview-stop-working-after-push-view-to-uinavigationcontroller?rq=1)

Comment: What do I have to import or set delegate to use resizeScrollViewContent?

Comment: @Churchill resizeScrollViewContent is a made up method that should contain the resizing code. you can instead just write self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1234, 5678); I just had this problem and this solves it. You should accept it as the correct answer!

Comment: mitul marsonia's answer combined with what figha said works now. As does the following line of code:
    - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
    {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1234, 5678);
    }

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem, but forgot to post it...

```
    - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
    {
        [self resizeScrollViewContent];
    }

    - (void) resizeScrollViewContent
    {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 468.0f);
    }
```

Or you could use this as well:

```
    - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
    {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 468.0f);
    }
```