# UIScrollView disabled after UINavigationController push and pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

**I have looked at the other answers to this question, and none of them have helped.**

I have a UIScrollView in my very simple scene, embedded like this:

[image]

I use this code to make sure the scroll view will actually scroll, based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831968/uiscrollview-scroll-not-working-after-pushed-with-a-navigation-controller/22832113#22832113).

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self resizeScrollView];
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self resizeScrollView];
}

- (void)resizeScrollView
{
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [_scrollView setContentSize:_innerView.frame.size];
}

- (IBAction)cameraButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that scrolling doesn't work after I've pushed and popped the new ViewController (Which originally was an image picker btw).

Comment: Is `_innerView`'s frame equal to or less than the size of the window that contains you're `UIScrollView`?

Comment: It is taller by about 100.

Comment: Try changing `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to `layoutSubviews` (call super)

Comment: Did you print logs of _innerView.frame.size when navigationController popping or pushing?

Comment: I did, and they were as they should be, always the same size, which is taller than the scrollview's frame, and the same size as the scrollview's contentsize.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked, but I wrapped everything in another view, and it's perfect now.

[image: dreamzarereal]

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem, unfortunately the fix you propose of adding another UIView behind the ScrollView doesn't seem to work for me..Any other suggestions of things you tried? thanks!